# New to PYTHON using Sublime TEXT“TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting” works on all other queries but this

Tags: python, string-formatting, typeerror

```
for fi in dirs:
    file_nm = fi
    if file_nm == "XXX_PRODCost.xlsx":
        print 'Beginning file:', file_nm
        wb=open_workbook('Labor_Cost' + '\\' + file_nm)
        sh=wb.sheet_by_name('New Dept Data')  
        values=[]
        for r in range(1, sh.nrows):
            v = [None]*8
            #v[0] = str(sh.cell(r,0).value)[:6] # YM
            v[3] = sh.cell(r,2).value  # 
            #v[1] = sh.cell(r,1).value # 
            v[0] = sh.cell(r,4).value # DEPT
            v[1] = sh.cell(r,5).value # DEPT Job
            v[4] = time  # append date
            v[2] = sh.cell(r,6).value # PROD #
            v[7] = sh.cell(r,7).value # 
            v[8] = sh.cell(r,3).value # 
            values.append(tuple(v))
    for i in lst_split(len(values)):
            cnxn.cursor().executemany('insert into LABOR."stgLaborFlagsX" values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', values[min(i):max(i)+1])
```

I continue to get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx_ALL.py", line 128, in <module>
    cnxn.cursor().executemany('insert into LABOR."xxxxPROD" values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', values[min(i):max(i)+1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\cursor.py", line 702, in executemany
    param, self))

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `insert` statement is expecting 7 data items, but your code is making a slice of the list `values` that has 8 or more elements. Print `values[min(i):max(i)+1])` before your `executemany()` call to diagnose the problem.